# Soldering sensitive components

Tags: capacitor, soldering, heat

I am working on a project called LM317 power supply.

The schematic is from the internet, and contains the regulator, filter capacitors, rectifier, potentiometer and protection diodes.

I designed a layout and I made the PCB. The PCB contains large copper pours.

When I started to solder I realized that using the soldering station at about 350C, the copper pour took all the heat and the joint was not good.

So I started to find a solution to this problem.

I took my soldering gun and I started to solder the components and I covered the copper pour with solder, to prevent oxidation.

After I soldered using the soldering gun, I realized that the capacitors were hot.

What should I do to check if the capacitors are still good ?

Can the heat destroy the electrolytic and ceramic capacitors while soldering ?

Comment: Many components state the soldering time and temperature on their datasheets; do you have the datasheets for your components?

Comment: This is why you have thermal reliefs for the solder pads.  Any electronic design package should offer them.

Comment: You can't really test the parts that are already soldered in place (except in special circumstances.)  So, finish putting it together and test it carefully when done.  Check for short circuits before applying power.

Comment: I don't know if the components have or not datasheet. I bought the components from the local electronics shop @PeterSmith  .

Comment: I redesigned and rebuilt the PCB using almost new components and using thermal reliefs @JRE .

Comment: Wow.  Quick work.